# Joining 3 tables from two different Databases?

Tags: mysql, sql, database

Database 1 (2 tables) : sandbox_maesc4

table 1: coordinates

```
+----------------------------------------+
|coord_id | section_name | station_number|
+----------------------------------------+
|   1     |    A         |  A7           |
|   2     |    B         |  B20          |
|   3     |    C         |  C3           |
|   4     |    D         |  D14          |
|   5     |    E         |  E9           |
+----------------------------------------+
```

table 2: workstation_userlogged

```
+----------------------------------+
|  id     |    ws         |  user  |
+----------------------------------+
|   1     |    COMP123    |  ryan  |
|   2     |    COMP345    |  luda  |
|   3     |    COMP567    |  chris |
|   4     |    COMP891    |  michel|
|   5     |    COMP444    |  isabel|
+----------------------------------+
```

Database 2 (1 table): softphone_materials_updater

Table 1: workstation

```
+----------------------------+
|   ID  |    ws     |  pod   |
+----------------------------+
|  1    |  COMP123  |  A07   |
|  2    |  COMP345  |  B20   |
|  3    |  COMP567  |  C03   |
|  4    |  COMP891  |  D14   |
|  5    |  COMP444  |  E09   |
+----------------------------+
```

**Problem:**

I only have read access in Database 2.
So I did a SELECT query for both fields and created the table "userlogged".

Now, I want to combine both tables "coordinates" and "userlogged" by joining table "workstation"
with their relation of the "station_number" field and "pod" field from. How can I achieve this? Below is the query that I tried but doesnt work.

I have extra fields in "coordinates" table (X,Y fields with actual coordinates). In PHP I use all fields to show them on screen.

```
SELECT 
  coordinate_id, 
  section_name, 
  x_coord, 
  y_coord, 
  ws.username, 
  ws.hostname, 
  w.pod, 
FROM 
  sandbox_maesc4.coordinates c, 
  sandbox_maesc4.workstation_userlogged ws
INNER JOIN
  softphone_materials_updater.workstations w
  ON c.station_number = w.pod
```

Comment: what exactly didnt work?

Comment: the query doesnt select the fields I want to display

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think maybe this is what you want?

```
SELECT 
  coordinate_id, 
  section_name, 
  x_coord, 
  y_coord, 
  wsu.username, 
  wsu.hostname, 
  w.pod 
FROM 
  sandbox_maesc4.coordinates c  
INNER JOIN
  softphone_materials_updater.workstations w
  ON c.station_number = w.pod
INNER JOIN
  sandbox_maesc4.workstation_userlogged wsu
  ON w.ws = wsu.ws
```

Not sure about the database and table names, they seem to differ between your sample query and the description.

Comment: I updated the names and all. Still the query you gave me does not work. The coordinates table has "x_coord" and "y_coord" fields which I did not include in the drawing. Thanks again

Comment: When you say it does not work what is the problem? Are you getting an error or are you just not getting the correct results? In your table descriptions there doesn't seem to be any _username_ and _hostname_ columns, maybe it should be _wsu.user as username_ and _wsu.ws as hostname_ ?

Comment: actually I just made it worked, there was an extra "," after the w.pod . I just modified the query to what it needs to be. thanks a lot!